# How can I regain control over a "stuck" scroll bar?

Tags: windows-7, browser, scrolling, scrollbar

I normally have a lot of tabs open in the browser at one time, which normally doesn't cause any problems.

Occasionally, though, the page will have fully rendered, the scroll bar is at the top of its track on the right, but placing the the mouse pointer on the scroll bar does not allow me to get control of it (and using the arrow at the bottom of the scroll bar doesn't work either).  This seems to happen to me in both Firefox and Chrome, both latest versions.  There is normally no load on the CPU, and while my memory usage can be high (especially with Chrome), I still usually have >25% left.

I fear that this is one of those "for your own good" features, to prevent scrolling down a page that may still have elements loading and/or a stuck script, but I'm wondering whether or not there is a setting in Firefox or Chrome (or perhaps Windows in general) that will allow the scroll bar to be "released" even though the browser may be busy?

It may be "2002" of me, but I wouldn't mind being able to scroll along gradually, even if the page hasn't had time to fully render all of the images, etc., yet.

Does such an advanced setting exist "under the hood"?

Comment: If someone thinks that this is incomplete somehow, I am open to suggestions.  I think it's a general problem that people face, and sometimes I have run across `about:config` settings that seem to work wonders.

Comment: If the browser is busy, it's unlikely that it could be forced to handle any scroll events.

Comment: @martineau That makes sense, but if the browser is constantly polling for new activity in the other tabs (e.g., with new questions on SE sites), I would think there would be a spare thread or two hanging around.  Again, I'm perhaps looking at it very naively, but how would the application completely lose focus?

Comment: There might be some spare threads, but the window's content is probably locked while the browser is busy updating it -- so it cannot be scrolled simultaneously.

Comment: Does it react to cursor or page keys?

Comment: I know the problem of unresponsive web browser when javascript is blocking the event loop. I always thought this is a serious browser flaw to dot hat kind of processing on the event loop - however all of them seems to do it (I have not seen it in Edge, however I don't use that one often enough to tell)